# Coding a For ... Next with dynamic Step

Tags: vba, excel

I've written a VBA code in Excel for trying to cycle through rows of data that contain author names and titles and placing "First" in the row for the first author and "Last" in the last author's row for the same title.

As the number of author's per article vary, I thought it easiest to use a Step to go to the next block of authors but the Step value of "y" does not have any impact on increasing the value "r" (the row number).

Code:

```
Sub AuthFirstPlacer()
    Dim r, cyclenum As Long
    Dim y As Variant 'did not work a Long either

    For r = 2 To 41 Step y
        cyclenum = Cells(r, 4).Value
        Cells(r, 6).Value = "First"
        y = r + cyclenum - 1          'this meant to move to next block of authors
        Cells(y, 6).Value = "Last"
    Next r
    ...
End Sub
```

The program runs fine except it does not Step at all. It goes from r=2 to r=3.
Y in the actual data is 22.

Comment: FYI that deleted post was not wrong about variable declaration. https://colinlegg.wordpress.com/2013/06/08/a-common-mistake-when-declaring-variables-in-vba/ . It just might not have been the issue

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you cannot change the stepsize of a for-loop after the program flow has entered the loop. Try this:

```
Sub AuthFirstPlacer()  
    Dim r as Long
    Dim cyclenum As Long
    Dim endrow As Long

    r = 2
    Do While r <= 41
        cyclenum = Cells(r, 4).Value
        Cells(r, 6).Value = "First"
        endrow = r + cyclenum - 1    ' move to last line in this block
        Cells(endrow, 6).Value = "Last"
        r = endrow + 1
    End Loop  
End Sub
```

Comment: I think that bottom `r = r + y` should be `r = y + 1` and it should be good to go once 41 is raised high enough to span a few publications.

Comment: You're right, corrected the code and use better variable name to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

In the VBA [For...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx) the *Step* is not a dynamic increment that can be adjusted on the fly. Your *y* variable is never given a value beyond what it was instantiated as when it was declared which was zero and that is the step. It is only after the fact that it receives a value.

If you want to skip over a number of records, use `Continue For`.

```
Sub AuthFirstPlacer()

    Dim r as long, cyclenum As Long

    For r = 2 To 41 Step 1
        if r <= cyclenum then continue for
        cyclenum = Cells(r, 4).Value + r - 1
        Cells(r, 6).Value = "First"
        Cells(cyclenum, 6).Value = "Last"
    Next r

end sub
```

That may not be completely correct as I have no sample data to test against but the method is sound. You may have to tweak where *cyclenum* gets a new value. If you have difficulties, post some sample data with expected results.

Comment: The original file has >2700 rows. The graphic shows on set with First and Last shown  for one article. <img src="http://i255.photobucket.com/albums/hh133/bobphoto22/sample.jpg">

Comment: So instead of copying and pasting a dozen redacted records into your original question, you'd prefer I type out several hundred entries so I can test against your data and provide you with a solution? Let me get back to you on that. [Why Not Images of Code and Sample Data](http://tinyurl.com/kdxb7le)

Comment: Not sure why the anger? I posted an image so you could see the issue. I don't know how to post the actual file. I do thank you for you help. Sorry for any grief my ignorance may have caused you.